# Get the current thread id on Windows 8 with C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

System.Threading.Thread (with .CurrentThread.ThreadId etc) has been removed from WinRT. Is it possible to get a current thread id (for debugging and logging purposes?) in Windows 8?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

See [`Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentmanagedthreadid.aspx) which is supported in windows store applications.

> **.NET for Windows Store apps**
>
> Supported in: Windows 8

Comment: The thread class is not supported in UWP, Tasks are available, can I cast it to Task in order to use this?

Answer (score 0):

back to the roots:

[GetCurrentThreadId function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `Retrieves the thread identifier of the calling thread.`

*WinBase.h on Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, and Windows Server 2008 R2 (include Windows.h);
Processthreadsapi.h on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012.*